# Format a big number to regular

Tags: php

Hello cannot found how to do this with php code, hope someone can help me..
Super simple I have this number **35675000000000000000**, I only have the number of decimals in this case **18**...
How can I format it to get the correct number **35.675**
The big number is a crypto balance from the blockchain.

Regards

Comment: Like `35675000000000000000 / pow(10,18)`?

Comment: Thanks JNevill work like a charm, u make my day :O)

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer from JNevill

```
$balanceFormated = $balance / pow(10, $decimals);
```

Big thanks